# fetch mysql data in map with data change on dragging radius

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to create map same as given in https://housing.com/in/rent/search?f=eyJsb2N0IjoiZXN0IiwiZXN0Ijp7ImlkIjoiMTk5MzYyIiwicmFkaXVzIjo2NTN9fQ%3D%3D but im not able to get how to get data from database which will have all points around the given center which will change on dragging the radius of map

Comment: Google map will do it for you. Look at google map API.

Comment: Website in the link is using Google map Api. So go for Google Map API as suggested by @nagiyevel

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easily understandable way is to first calculate the distance between the circle's center and the point. I would use this formula:

`d = sqrt((circle_x - x)^2 + (circle_y - y)^2)`

Then, simply compare the result of that formula, the distance (`d`), with the radius. If the distance (`d`) is less than or equal to the radius (`r`), the point is inside the circle (on the edge of the circle if `d` and `r` are equal).

Comment: This will not work as I had to find the points covered by covered radius.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  load_detail_id,s_city,s_latitude,d_latitude,s_longitude,d_longitude,
3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(($s_latitude -abs(dest.s_latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS($s_latitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest.s_latitude) *pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(($s_longitude - dest.s_longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance FROM m_load_detail dest having distance < $radius